# Is Java EE required for Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Are there extra Java EE libraries required to run Hibernate standalone Java applications, or is the standard SDK sufficient?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hibernate works just fine on Java SE. It can be used as a JPA implementation on Java EE, but JPA, as well, can be used just fine on Java SE.

Answer (score 3):

Java EE is not required to run Hibernate.  I think a good place to start is with the Hibernate documentation. I think it is very intuitive and easy to follow.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/tutorial-firstapp.html

You can also find the jar files to download here:  https://www.hibernate.org/344.html

Answer (score 1):

Any JPA provider, including Hibernate, can be used outside of a Java EE container. There are some instructions for a few providers in [ORMs vs SQL: The JPA Story](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/orms-vs-sql-jpa-story.html).